# failed to find target with hash string 'android-10'

Tags: android, android-espresso

When i first try to clone project and run it from command line I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find target with hash string 'android-10'
```

But when I load the project in android studio and then run the test from command line the test runs fine.

I do not want to open android studio to resolve the issue and handle it from command line it self. Can some one please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find target with hash string 'android-10

You need to have API 10 installed on your machine to build this project as checked out.

Comment: My project supports minimum API 19,installing API 10 is giving me failure is there a way i can assign API 19 in my project.  The build.gradle file in app folder already has API 19 specified, so I am not sure where API 10 is coming from when I try to run the test from command line(when I dont open the android studio at all). Once i open the android studio all error goes and my test runs fine from command line.

Comment: have you searched your project for `android-10` string to see why it even shows up?

Comment: Yes I have already searched for android-10 and nothing found.

Comment: so what **exactly** you do that triggers this error?

Comment: I clone my prject and run the   ./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest  -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=test.espresso.Gas_mip that triggers the error. then i open android studio and run the above command again and the error goes. I think when i open android studio my app-> build.gradle file shows min API 19 and test runs fine..but when i run from command prompt somehow it has API 10 as default and my test fails

Comment: I found the solution to it, my ANDROID_HOME was pointing to the wrong location hence by default it tried using Android 10.

Comment: Great you solved the issue. Please post this as answer and mark as accepted answer to close the question

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID_HOME was pointing to the wrong location hence by default it tried using Android 10. I changed the ANDROID_HOME value in bash profile.